# Do I need a transit Visa in one of the airports

Tags: kenyan-citizens

I am a Kenyan citizen ,wuld like to travel to Cayman islands from Nairobi through Dubai to Frankfurt using Emirates airlines, from  Frankfurt to Panama with a different airline. so will I need any transit Visa in Dubai or in Frankfurt bearing in mind that Kenyans don't require a visa to Cayman islands and Panama? And if I get to Frankfurt will the airlines check in my luggage to the next flight since I will change the airlines in Frankfurt Germany?

Comment: Are all flights on a single ticket/booking? What is the second airline? If the flights are on separate tickets, you most probably will have to reclaim bags and check them back in (before the check-in deadline), and will most definitely need a visa to enter the Schengen Area. You will also have to rebook (at your own cost) the flight (and possibly the return flight as well) if the first flight is delayed and you miss the deadline (you will be considered a no-show).

Comment: The second airline is Lufthansa airlines from Frankfurt to Panama on a separate ticket